# Restlet - how to expose a resource with both HTTP/HTTPS?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, restlet

Using restlet 2.3.1. I've a resource exposed via HTTP. Is it possible to expose it via HTTPS as well? The following snippet show how my server looks like today:

```
final Router router = new Router();

Filter filter = new Filter(){};

filter.setNext( DaemonsResource.class );
router.attach( "daemons/{p1}", filter );

Application myApp = new Application() 
{
    @Override
    public org.restlet.Restlet createInboundRoot()
    {
        router.setContext(getContext());

        return router;
    };
};

Component component = new Component();

component.getDefaultHost().attach( "/", myApp );

new Server( Protocol.HTTP, port, component ).start();
```

I already got the crt from the CA, and built the keystore upon it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
Component component = new Component();
Server server = component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTPS, 8082);

component.getDefaultHost().attach( "/", myApp );
component.start();
```

See [restlet tutorials](https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/tutorials/2.3/rest-concepts)

To set your keystore, etc.,

```
Series<Parameter> parameters = server.getContext().getParameters();
parameters.add("keystorePath","add_keystore_file_path_here"));
parameters.add("keystorePassword", "mypassword");
parameters.add("keyPassword", "mypassword");
parameters.add("keystoreType", "PKCS12");  

// Start the component.
component.start();
```

see [restlet mailing list](http://restlet-discuss.1400322.n2.nabble.com/SSL-in-restlet-td1693602.html) This message is a bit outdated but the parameters should still be the same